# Is the resultant, the locus of the center of the circle?

Tags: circles, locus

> If a circle $C$ passing through the point $(4,0)$ touches the circle $x^2 + y^2 + 4x − 6y = 12$ externally at the point $(1,−1)$, then the radius of $C$ is?

I have a question here, I have two points here on the circle $C$, $(4,0)$ and, $(1,-1)$ then the distance between the center point let's say $(x,y)$ and the two points will be equal.

So when I equate both of them I get this equation $6x+2y-14=0$ isn't this line the locus of the center of the circle?

If it is then why the radius is wrong when I used the *distance of a point from a line*, the line being $6x+2y-14=0$ and the point being $(1,-1)$?

Here is the link to this question: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-a-circle-c-passing-through-the-point-4-0/

Comment: you've nowhere used the other circle : $(x+2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 25$, centered at $(-2,3)$ with a radius of $5$

Comment: your circle just touches the other circle. We know that the line joining the two centres of a circle passes through their intersection point (or the mid-point of the intersection points, if there are 2), so the sum of distances from the centre of both circles to $(1,-1)$ is equal to the distance between the two centres

Comment: How can that influence the answer? Where I am wrong? If it touches doesn't it mean that that point lies on it?

Comment: both the circles touch each other at $(1,-1)$ means that they only meet at $1$ point, which is a fundamental property

Comment: So? how that solved the query? I am not getting it.

Comment: please wait, I'm typing the answer, it is too long for a comment

Comment: The point `(1,-1)` will not be the passing point, I got it now, thanks to CHATgpt

Answer (score 1):

The given circle can be written

$$( x+2)^2+(y-3)^2=5^2 $$

that has center at $(-2,3)$ and radius $5.$

Finding  the continuation line $CEG$ equation when RHS is evaluated at $ E (1,-1):$

$$\frac{y-3}{x+2}=\frac{-4}{3} \to 4 x +3 y= 1 \tag 1 $$

Next, you have already found the perpendicular bisector locus line as

$$3 x +y = 7 \tag 2$$

Solving equations 1,2 the center point coordinates are found as

$$ (x,y)= (4,-5) \tag 3 $$

It is given that the point  passes through
$$ (4,0) \tag 4 $$

[image]

The distance between above two points is easily found out, as the radius length, equal to 5.

Answer (score -1):

The eq. of tangent to $S=x^2+y^2+4x-6y-12=0$ at the point $(1,-1)$ is
$L=x-y+2(x+1)-3(y-1)12=0\implies L=3x-4y-7=0$. Next the  equation family of curves  touching S and L externally is nothing but $$S'=S+tL= x^2+y^2+4x-6y-12+3tx-4ty-7t=0$$

Now let $S'$ pass through (4,0) to get the  $t=-4$ to fix the required circle C as  $x^2+y^2-8x+10y=-16.$

Comment: yes thanks, I have corrected it now.